# How to add a pop-up message to my MDI GUI in Java

Tags: java, awt

I would like to add a pop-up message/message box to my MDI GUI whereby when the user clicks "Exit" for example, the pop-up message asks "Are you sure you want to Exit?" with two choices. The program should cease/close when user clicks btnYes and cont. when user clicks btnNo

```
//Exit FileMenu Option Should close the program when user clicks

private void mnExitActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       

    System.exit(0);

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using JOptionPane you can make a popup that prompts the user for this.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html

Eg:

```
int n = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog, frame, "Are you sure you want to exit?", "WINDOW NAME", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
```

Comment: Thank you, very helpful